# Correct approach to handle similar but different types of objects like user accounts

Tags: php

I am starting a new web project. And I have some questions about handling user accounts. I have some basic OOP knowledge but new with PHP.

My scenario is very familiar. There will be two different type of accounts. Customers and Companies. They will have some shared and particular properties.
In database I will use three tables for storing user data. One for shared properties. Others will be for specific information on the type of user.

**shared_data**

```
+---------+-----------------------+---------------+----------+----------+--------+
| user_id |         email         |   user_name   | password |   type   | active |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------+----------+----------+--------+
|       1 | mail@supercompany.com | Super Company | secret   | company  |      1 |
|       2 | mail@boldcompany      | Bold Company  | cetres   | company  |      1 |
|       3 | johndoe@mail.com      | John Doe      | retsec   | customer |      1 |
|       4 | janedoe@mail.com      | Jane Doe      | setrec   | customer |      1 |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

**company_only_data**

```
+---------+-----------------+------------------+
| user_id | company_address | person_in_charge |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+
|       1 | Berlin          | Steven Seagal    |
|       2 | Budapest        | Chuck Norris     |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+
```

**user_only_data**

```
+---------+--------+--------------+
| user_id | gender | last_shoping |
+---------+--------+--------------+
|       3 | male   | never        |
|       4 | female | yesterday    |
+---------+--------+--------------+
```

I don't want to reinvent the whell. As user handling is one of the essential step of web programming I thought I'd find better resources about that subject. I read many articles including "**abstract classes and interfaces**" but none of them was clear.

My plan is construct something like below

```
class UserManager
{
    private $user_id;

    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        //Return joined data of shared_data table
        //and second table (based on type of account)

    }

    public function deactivate()
    {
        //Update shared_data set active=0 WHERE user_id = $this->user_id
    }

    public function login()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        //...
    }
}

class CustomerManager extends UserManager
{
    public function getShoppingData()
    {
        //Return results of shopping_data table for $this->user_id
    }

    //...some other customer related methods
}

class CompanyManager extends UserManager
{
    public function getSalesReport()
    {
        //Work with results of sales_data table for $this->user_id
    }

    //...some other company related methods
}
```

Am I on the right track or doing something wrong?

Can you suggest me some well documented links to start with or suggest me an approach?

Comment: could you tell us why you try to build something like user management from scratch .. you can use a framework or maybe CMS .. you do not need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface to set the common methods and attributes. by using interfaces, you make sure that all your classes have the minimum set of methods and attributes your app logic requires (like login, logout, commonDetails, etc)

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.